# Error in executing OWBClient.sh in UNIX

Tags: unix, jvm, oracle-warehouse-builder

I am trying to run the OWBClient.sh with the command in UNIX and I am getting the following error:
" The JVM option is invalid: -XX: MaxPermSize=256M. Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."

OWB Version: 10.2.0.5
Oracle Database : 10g
UName: AIX

When exploring more on the above issue, I got an information that OWB 10.2 could not be run in AIX. It would be helpful if anyone can can shed some light on whether OWB 10.2.0.5 can be run on AIX?

Editing my post to share an update.I have tried to execute the owbclient.sh file by removing the -XX:MaxPermSize=256M part. I am now getting a different kind of error...

$ ./owbclient.sh

[Launcher]:  Error! Cannot find and load the jar file '../../../jdk/jre/lib/                                                                                                                     rt.jar'. OWB application may not be launched due to this error.

[Launcher]:  Error! Cannot find and load the jar file '../../../jdk/jre/lib/                                                                                                                     jce.jar'. OWB application may not be launched due to this error.

StaticLoader: Setting locale to en__
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                                                     java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                                                     java:58)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                                                                     sorImpl.java:60)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
        at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:167)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0                                                                                                                     .0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:1                                                                                                                     75)
        at java.lang.Class.forName1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:180)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvi                                                                                                                     ronment.java:91)
        at sun.awt.motif.MToolkit.(MToolkit.java:124)
        at java.lang.Class.forName1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:180)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:796)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged1(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:287                                                                                                                     )
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:787)
        at java.awt.Component.getToolkitImpl(Component.java:873)
        at java.awt.Component.getToolkit(Component.java:857)
        at java.awt.Component.createImage(Component.java:2729)
        at oracle.wh.ui.common.CommonUtils.getIcon(CommonUtils.java:622)
        at oracle.wh.ui.framework.beans.splash.SplashBean.setImageLoc(SplashBean                                                                                                                     .java:111)
        at oracle.wh.ui.framework.beans.splash.SplashBean.(SplashBean.java                                                                                                                     :42)
        at oracle.wh.ui.framework.StaticLoader.main(StaticLoader.java:67)
        ... 6 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
$

Comment: You might want to find out the versions of AIX and java. Try commands `oslevel` and `java -version`. Also you could edit the script in question and remove the `-XX:MaxPermSize=256M` part (this option is obsolete now)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The output for oslevel is 5.3.0.0 but when I executed the command java -version, it throws the message "ksh : java : not found". I will try to remove the -XX:MaxPermSize=256M part and will let you know the output.

Comment: Ask your sys-admin to install JRE (or JRE+JDK), and to add its bin directory to the PATH. Java can be downloaded from IBM (requires free registration); the maximum Java version for aix5.3 is Java6

Comment: I have contacted the admin team and they confirmed that JRE is already installed in the system and the above mentioned setup is already in place. Could you please suggest if there is anything else that needs to be checked upon? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to locate java's directory so that you could add it to the PATH. Command `ls -ld /usr/java*` could be a start.